# Error on request to Keycloak for obtain jwt sending autorizathion code

Tags: node.js, keycloak, nestjs

I am implementing the authorization code flow with Nestjs and keycloak, I have already redirected the login request to the keycloak login page, I received the authorization code and when making the post to the callback url, I get the following error:

> Converting circular structure to JSON
> -> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
> | property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'Socket'
> --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle

I noticed that this error happens only after passing the authorization code as a parameter:

follow the code:

```
import { HttpException, HttpService, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { KeycloakConnectModule } from 'nest-keycloak-connect';
import * as queryString from 'querystring'
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

private keycloakLoginUri: string;
private keycloakResponseType: string;
private keycloakScope: string;
private keycloakRedirectUri: string;
private keycloakGrantType: string;
private keycloakClientId: string;
private keycloakClientSecret: string;
private keycloakTokenUri: string;

constructor(  readonly _config: ConfigService, private readonly _http: HttpService) {
    this.keycloakLoginUri = _config.get('KEYCLOAK_LOGIN_URI');
    this.keycloakResponseType = _config.get('KEYCLOAK_RESPONSE_TYPE');
    this.keycloakScope = _config.get('KEYCLOAK_SCOPE');
    this.keycloakRedirectUri = _config.get('KEYCLOAK_REDIRECT_URI');
    this.keycloakGrantType = 'authorization_code';
    this.keycloakClientId = _config.get('KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID'); 
    this.keycloakClientSecret = _config.get('KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET');
    this.keycloakTokenUri = this._config.get('KEYCLOAK_TOKEN_URI');
}

getLoginUrl(): any {
    return { url: `${this.keycloakLoginUri}`
        +`?client_id=${this.keycloakClientId}`
        +`&response_type=${this.keycloakResponseType}`
        +`&scope=${this.keycloakScope}`
        +`&redirect_uri=${this.keycloakRedirectUri}`
    }
}

getKeyCloakToken(code: string){
    const params =  {
        grant_type: this.keycloakGrantType,
        client_id: this.keycloakClientId,
        client_secret: this.keycloakClientSecret,
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: this.keycloakRedirectUri
    };

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }

    
    return this._http.post(
        this.keycloakTokenUri, 
        queryString.stringify(params),
        config)
    .pipe(catchError(e => {
        throw new HttpException(e.response.data, e.response.status);
    }));
}
}
```

Enviroments variables difined on .env

```
KEYCLOAK_LOGIN_URI=http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/onboarding-arqt/protocol/openid-connect/auth
KEYCLOAK_AUTH_URI=http://localhost:8080/auth
KEYCLOAK_TOKEN_URI=http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/onboarding-arqt/protocol/openid-connect/token?
KEYCLOAK_GRANT_TYPE=authorization_code
KEYCLOAK_REALM=my-realm
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID=my-id
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET=my-secret
KEYCLOAK_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:3000/callback
KEYCLOAK_SCOPE=profile
KEYCLOAK_RESPONSE_TYPE=code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be mapping the response of the `httpService`. Axios (what the `HttpService` uses under the hood) returns a circular object as it's return, so you need to map it to what you expect. Most likely, adding this line in the `pipe` will fix it

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

...
return this._http.post(whatever).pipe(
  map((res) => res.data),
  catchError(e => { throw new HttpException(e.response.data, e.response.status);}),
);
...
```

By the way, now that you've publicly posted your keycloak information, make sure to rotate the keys and generate new secure data. Otherwise, your application may as well not have authentication at all and be completely compromised.

Comment: Thank you @Jay McDoniel, these keycloak data are local, for testing only